# Bug Tracker для приложения

Tags: android

Посоветуйте, пожалуйста, хороший бесплатный bug tracker с анонимной оправкой отчета (т.е. если приложение упало, отчеты отправлялись бы автоматически)
AppFabric пробовал не удобно показалось, стандартное решение от Google тоже не подходит.

Какие используете вы?

Comment: Пробовал fabric и acra, не знаю как сейчас, но чтобы завести acra нужно было выполнить не малый квест, fabic на ура встал и устраивает всем.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте для этих целей [Flurry](https://developer.yahoo.com/flurry/docs/analytics/)

Можете отслеживать [активность пользователей/ошибки](https://developer.yahoo.com/flurry/)

Answer (score 1):

[ACRA](https://github.com/ACRA/acra)

Сообщения об ошибке можно отправлять разными способами (молча или через e-mail).

Но нужно свой back-end для приёма сообщений. В моём случае это был простейший php-скрипт, коий складывал сообщения в БД.